# c++ bugs out when trying to find vector<struct>.begin()/.end()

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, vector, iterator

So there is this thing bugging me in my project, that prevents me to find the vector.begin() and vector.end() when putting struct as the vector type. Anyone can help me there?

```
struct product
{
    string name = "";
    int qty = 0, code = 0, cat = 0;
    double price = 0.00;
}

(...)
vector <product> prod;
(...)
for(int i = 0; i != prod.end(); i++) //error here
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This should be an error. An iterator and an index are different things. You may want a range based for loop instead of either. `for (auto& prd : prod) { // do something with prd}`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i != prod.end(); i++)
```

there are compared an object of the type int and an object of the type either `std::vector<product>::iterator` or `std::vector<product>::const_iterator`

There is no operator != defined for operands of these types.

It seems you mean something like

```
for ( auto it = prod.begin(); it != prod.end(); ++it)
```

or

```
for ( auto it = std::begin( prod ); it != std::end( prod ); ++it)
```

and to access an element of the vector you should use either expression `*it` or `it` with the operator `->` as if `it` is a pointer. For example `( *it ).qty` or `it->qty`.

or

```
for ( std::vector<product>::size_type i = 0; i != prod.size(); i++ )
```

and in this case you may use the subscript operator as for example `prod[i].qty`.

Pay attention to that the loops will not make a sense for an empty vector.

Another approach is to use the range based for loop like for example

```
for ( const auto &p : prod )
```

or

```
for ( auto &p : prod )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! the "for ( std::vector<product>::size_type i = 0; i != prod.size(); i++ )" solution worked fine for me